# Help proving a subset with absolute value?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm in need of help with the following proof:

Let $D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\hspace{0.1cm}\big|\hspace{0.1cm}-7<x<-2\}$ and $E=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\hspace{0.1cm}\big|\hspace{0.1cm}4>|x+5|\}$. Prove that $D\subseteq E$.

I know how to do subset proofs (let $x$ fall arbitrarily in $D$, then end up showing that $x$ is in $E$). My problem is that I don't understand how to do that. Any member of $D$ falls in a pretty unhelpful open interval. Also, I am absolutely clueless about absolute values and their associated rules (I missed one lesson in HS and it's coming back to bite me!) Is a direct approach the correct approach? It seems like direct is going to be impossible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to find a simpler way to express $E$. Hint: $|a|\lt b\Rightarrow -b\lt a\lt b$

Comment: Note that $E$ is the set of all real numbers which are less than $4$ units away from $-5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When handling absolute values such as the one in $E=\{x\in\textbf{R}\hspace{0.1cm}\big|\hspace{0.1cm}4>|x+5|\}$, there are two related inequalities we can form that are easier to work with without the absolute values: $$4 > x + 5 \qquad \text{and}\qquad -4 < x + 5.$$ Notice how the inequality on the left is the original inequality with the absolute value removed, and the one on the right is the original inequality with the absolute value removed, the direction swapped, and the other side negative. Rearrangement of these two intervals gives us: $$-1 > x \qquad \text{and}\qquad -9 < x$$ $$\implies x < -1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad x > -9$$ $$\implies -9 < x < -1\qquad\text{by observation}.$$

Consider the set $D=\{x\in\textbf{R}\hspace{0.1cm}\big|\hspace{0.1cm}-7<x<-2\}$. Clearly $D\subset E$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A useful way to think about sets like $ \{x:|x+a|<b\}$ is to realise that this is the same as all $x$ which lie within a distance of $b$ from $-a$ (see why this is true). Having done this, you can rewrite $E$ similar to $D$ and that will lead you right to your answer.